# Browserify - bower vs npm node modules

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, bower, browserify

I don't really know where the `bower_components` directory came from in my `Node Express` app but it seems to be competing for attention with my `node_modules` folder since both contain `jquery` and `bootstrap`.

I am using Browserify and am trying to bundle up jquery, bootstrap and some other components. What exactly is going on here with Bower? Do I need Bower for anything?

For instance, when I do a `require('jquery')` in my application code how do I know if it's coming from the NPM node_modules or Bower bower_components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic browserify can only use `node_modules`.

To use with bower, it can use `transform` before import `node_modules`.

- If you use [debowerify](https://github.com/eugeneware/debowerify) transform, it will import `bower_components` before `node_modules`. So if your `bower.json` has `jquery` and `bootstrap`, it will use `bower_components'`.
- If you use [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim) transform, it will search your package.json's `browser` field. So if your `browser` field has `jquery` and `bootstrap`, it will use it.